# Declare a Table Variable Based on Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, initializer

I want to declare a table variable and fill it with a select, without having to explicitly define its columns.  Does T-SQL allow something like this:

```
DECLARE @people TABLE() SELECT * FROM Persons;
```

Hypothetically, the above statement would match column types identically, and fill the @people table variable at the same time. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do it with a table variable since a variable has to be declared before it can be used,  but you could use a temp table instead.

```
SELECT * INTO #people FROM Persons;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. The syntax for declaring table variables don't allow for something so dynamic.